# How to OR multiple filter calls in python

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I have the following code in Python that takes in several filters. Then I have a loop that calls .filter on each of them. However when you call multiple filters these are ANDed. How can I change it so that the multiple calls to filter are ORed. The problem is in the "else" part of my code.

```
for filter_ in filters:
        field_models = {'type': ProductType, 'category': ProductCategory}
        if filter_['field'] in field_models:
            model = field_models[filter_['field']]
            organizations_products = organizations_products.join(model).filter(or_(
                model.code.ilike('%{}%'.format(escape_like(filter_['value']))),
                model.description.ilike('%{}%'.format(escape_like(filter_['value'])))
            ))
        else:
            field = getattr(Product, filter_['field'])
            organizations_products = organizations_products.filter(
                field.ilike('%{}%'.format(escape_like(filter_['value']))))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two parts to the solution. First, we must construct the `from` clause, and then the `where` clause.

```
def get_joined_stmt(filters, stmt):
    if 'type' in filters.keys():
        stmt = stmt.join(ProductType)
    if 'category' in filters.keys():
        stmt = stmt.join(ProductCategory)
    return stmt

def get_exprs(field, value):
    def _ilike_expr(x): return '%{}%'.format(escape_like(x))

    model_dict = {'type': ProductType, 'category': ProductCategory}
    model = model_dict[field]
    stmt = organizations_products.join(model)
    try: 
        return [model.code.ilike(_ilike_expr(value)),
                model.description.ilike(_ilike_expr(value))]
    except KeyError:
        return [getattr(Product, field).ilike(_ilike_expr(value))]

organizations_products = get_joined_stmt(filters, organizations_products)

where_exprs = []
for filter_ in filters.items():
    where_exprs.extend(get_exprs(**filter_))

organizations_products = organizations_products.filter(or_(*where_exprs))
```

Comment: This is very useful code to help me learn a more flexible approach.

Answer (score 0):

Just build up a list of filters and `or_` them at the end:

```
exprs = []
for filter_ in filters:
    exprs.append(field.ilike(...))
organizations_products = organizations_products.filter(or_(*exprs))
```

By the way, implementing search like this is a terrible way to go performance-wise (unless you're on PostgreSQL and have a trigram index, in which case ignore this). You're much better served by using the fulltext search features of your DB.